# Update on record would update all other records in model, global ordering in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to update all records in a rails (3.1) model when i update an attribute on a single record.

Like self.update_attribute(:global_order => 1) then before or after save a would like to update all other records to update thier global_order (1, 2, 3, 4).

Right now with on after_save callback I get caught in a recursive loop, is skip callbacks the way to go? I would like the app to throw exceptions if anything seems strange in global_order.

Or are there any 3.1 gems that would solve my issue.

```
after_save :set_global_order

def set_global_order
    @products = self.class.all(:order => :global_order)
    @products.sort! {|a,b| a.global_order <=> b.global_order}
    @products.reverse!
    @products.each_with_index do |p, index|
        p.update_attributes!({:global_order => index + 1})
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's a gem, but you could definitely refactor this with the following considerations:

- No need to pollute the object with an instance variable when a local one will do
- The first three lines are sorting the same set, why not do that once?

...

```
def set_global_order
  products = self.class.order('global_order DESC')

  products.each_with_index do |p, index|
    p.update_column(:global_order, index + 1)
  end
end
```

Comment: This will not solve my issue with running recursive in a after_save callback. Is there any way to skip callbacks or how would you solve the problem.

Comment: Ah good point, I updated my answer to use `update_column` instead. I believe this is the only method that skips callbacks. Though, looking at the source for this method, it's slightly confusing and appears to be updating every record with the same value. You might need to experiment with it a little. There's also a `write_attribute` method which is called by update_column. I would try this as well if it turns out that update_column is updating all the records.

Comment: `update_column`does as you say updating a single record. Thanks for the hint. Still having trouble ordering the list of products, started looking at `acts_as_list` but seems hard do use on the same model without a scope.